# Find fan speed and cpu temp in Linux

Tags: fan

What are the commands to find out fan speed and cpu temp in linux (I know lm-sensor can do the task). Is there any alternative for that?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

**For CPU temperature:**

On Debian:

```
sudo apt-get install lm-sensors
```

On Centos:

```
sudo yum install lm_sensors
```

Run using:

```
sudo sensors-detect
```

Type `sensors` to get CPU temp.

**For fan speed:**

`sensors | grep -i fan`

This will output fan speed

or install `psensor` using:

```
sudo apt-get install psensor
```

One can also use `hardinfo`

```
sudo apt-get install hardinfo
```

Comment: sensors |grep fan doesn't output anything at all!

Comment: @matteo Case matters. On my system it is "Processor Fan", so use 'grep -i fan'

Comment: The sensors have to be detected first by running sensors-detect after installation (interactive terminal script, just pres Enter on questions and all have to be done automagically). This is needed on CentOS, on Debian configure/reconfigure is fired after install or dpkg-reconfigure psensor).

Comment: On my i5-8265U CPU `sensors-detect` cannot detect the fans, so `sensors` cannot show them either. [I asked for a solution here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1162598/show-fan-speed-of-i5-8265u-cpu-in-kubuntu)

Comment: In addition to @MilanKerslager point, after `sensors-detect` has listed your sensors, you need to check that the kernel driver modules are also installed.

Answer (score 48):

If you would like to try a different option, you can try s-tui, a software we were working on. It is a terminal UI app, so running it over SSH is also possible. 
It displays CPU temperature, utilization, frequency and power. 
Fan speed was also added.

Installation methods are explained on the GitHub Readme. 
[s-tui on GitHub](https://github.com/amanusk/s-tui)

This is a screenshot of what it looks like
[image: s-tui screenshot]

Comment: Thanks after many days got a response on question. i was using lm-sensor as suggested by others. will defiantly try this new software. thanks !!!

Comment: Looks impressive and I like the terminal eye candy!

Comment: Works great on Linux. I hope that it would have some OSX support soon.

Comment: Can it log values? I'm facing random hard system crashes, and would like to see if any of fan/temperature etc. correlate.

Answer (score 6):

I have used [ipmitool](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-ipmitool) from [GitHub](https://github.com/ipmitool/ipmitool/wiki) and [freeipmi](https://www.gnu.org/software/freeipmi) on my servers, but, well, they're servers, with [BMC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligent_Platform_Management_Interface#Baseboard_management_controller) hardware which supports [IPMI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligent_Platform_Management_Interface). If your PC does, it's a reasonable solution.

I run a script which pulls SDR data on the machine in test (example lines follow)

```
ti=$(date +%H:%M:%S)
pt=$(ipmitool -I open sdr | grep 'PS1 Temp')
```

and sends it to the screen as well as to logfile then idles w/ ping for 15 seconds

```
echo "$ti|$pt" && echo "$ti|$pt" >> logfile && ping -w 15 127.0.0.1 > nul
```

before looping around again for another pass.

Answer (score 5):

an alternative for lmsensor:

install xsensors using `sudo apt-get install xsensors`

Answer (score 4):

i'm use Glances in python. It's a interactive process manager and hardware status.

```
apt install python python-pip; pip install glances;
```

and run with:

```
glances
```

good look ;)

Comment: Can you show how it allows the user to find out fan speed and CPU temperature?

Comment: @G-Man check this https://github.com/nicolargo/glances/issues/1087, I havent tested yet tho

Answer (score 2):

GUI alternative for `sensors` command are [Psensor](http://wpitchoune.net/psensor/) and XSensors:

```
sudo apt install xsensors
sudo apt install psensor
```

For better detection of your hardware's sensors, you can also run following:

```
sudo apt install lm-sensors
sudo sensors-detect
sensors
watch -d -n 1 sensors
```